# Best approach to Timeout using HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse

Tags: c#, asynchronous, httpwebrequest, timeout, waithandle

HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse doesn´t respect any Timeout properties from HttpWebRequest(Timeout or ReadWriteTimeout).

I read some approaches to get the same results, but I don't know if it's the best way to do it and if I should use for few calls or I can scale it inside loops(I am doing a webcrawler).

The important thing is, initially my code isn´t async, I just need async because my method should accept a CancellationToken.

My concern is about WaitHandles and ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject. It isn´t a daily code then I don´t know if I can have problems in the near future.

```
private static void HandleCancellation(HttpWebRequest request, IAsyncResult getResponseResult, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    using (WaitHandle requestHandle = getResponseResult.AsyncWaitHandle)
    {
        ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(requestHandle, TimeoutCallback, request, request.Timeout, true);

        //If request finish or cancellation is called
        WaitHandle.WaitAny(new[] {requestHandle, cancellationToken.WaitHandle});
    }

    //If cancellation was called
    if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        request.Abort();
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }
}
```

Calling(again, it isn´t async)

```
IAsyncResult getResponseResult = request.BeginGetResponse(null, null);

HandleCancellation(request, getResponseResult, cancellationToken);

return (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(getResponseResult);
```

Reference: [Better approach in management of multiple WebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720113/better-approach-in-management-of-multiple-webrequest)

Comment: What problem is it causing you, do you have lots of async requests using resources waiting for timeout?  Why not let it just time-out.

Comment: Haven't you considered to use TPL?

Comment: Where should I use TPL? I am using Tasks to call this method, but not inside the method

Comment: @BenRobinson my webcrawler let me configure how many simultaneous download I do. If I let it timeout, when I call the cancellation token I need to wait all downloads timeout

Answer (score 3):

The MSDN documentation for [BeginGetResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse.aspx) has a very good example of how to handle timeouts. It worked quite well for me in my Web crawler.

Comment: I am doing something similar, but I am using WaitHandle.WaitAny instead of ManualResetEvent. It allows a cleaner code